# Golang Correctly Handle Stdin of SSH Session

Tags: go, ssh

I'm writing a program that uses the Go program to change the root password. The code snippet is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/pkg/sftp"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type ServerConfig struct {
    sshHost string
    sshUser string
    sshPassword string
    sshType string
    sshPort int
}

func main() {
    server := ServerConfig{
        sshHost: "172.28.128.3",
        sshUser: "vagrant",
        sshPassword: "*****",
        sshPort: 22,
        sshType: "password",
    }
    sshClient := SSHConnet(server)
    defer sshClient.Close()
    session,err := sshClient.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("creat ssh session fail",err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.Stdout = os.Stdout
    session.Stderr = os.Stdout
    session.Stdin = os.Stdin
    err = session.Run("su -; whoami")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

I will still be prompted for failed authentication even after entering the correct root password. Can someone help me?Thank you very much

```
go run main.go
Password: ******
su: Authentication failure
vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if this is because of your remote server settings.

See [for instance this](https://askubuntu.com/a/446572/5470), if said remote server is an Ubuntu one:

> The root account is disabled by default in Ubuntu, so there is no root password, that's why `su` fails with an authentication error.
>
> Use `sudo` to become root:
>
> ```
> sudo -i
> ```

Comment: Probably not, because I have no problem logging in root in Xshell, but it fails to run in code

Comment: OK. Did you check, just to be sure, if `sudo -i` worked?

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with `sudo -i`.